# Unable to build SSIS package from command line: Missing switch argument. Configuration name required for /build switch

Tags: ssis

I am trying to script out the building of an SSIS solution in VS 2013.

I keep getting the error: `Missing switch argument. Configuration name required for /build switch.`

[image]

My Command is this from PowerShell:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE> .\devenv.exe C:\Dev\SSIS\RCLShippedFileProcess\RCLShippedFileProcess.sln /build /project RCLShippedFile /projectconfig "Debug"
```

When I build within Visual Studio, I can see that my ProjectName and the Config are what I am passing in. This certainly has me stumped!

[image]

Documentation about this is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/b20w810z(v=vs.120)).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving the issue, I needed to call the `devenv.com` application, which is ultimately what `devenv.exe` calls. If you call `devenv.com` directly it worked.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE> .\devenv.exe C:\Dev\SSIS\RCLShippedFileProcess\RCLShippedFileProcess.sln /build "Debug"
```